# isEvenSubset did not return 1

Tags: java

Here is the Question: An integer is defined to be an even subset of another integer n if every even factor of m is also a factor of n. For example 18 is an even subset of 12 because the even factors of 18 are 2 and 6 and these are both factors of 12. But 18 is not an even subset of 32 because 6 is not a factor of 32.

**This is a University's sample question; the question, explicitly, states:** No additional data structures including arrays allowed - therefore, please consider that too while providing answer. Thank you.

Here is my answer code:

```
public class IsEvenSubset {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isEvenSubset(18,12));
    }
    private static int isEvenSubset(int m, int n){
        for(int i=2;i<=m;i++){
            int count=0;//reset count in each round
            if(m%2==0 && m%i==0){
                for(int j=2;j<=n;j++){
                    if(n%2==0 && n%j==0){
                        if(i==j)count++;
                    }
                }
                if(count==0)return 0;
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

This code didn't work as desired. Please help me figure out where did I do wrong?

Comment: Why does it return an `int`? Shouldn't it be a `boolean` instead? m either is or isn't an even subset of n.

Comment: @Sweeper Probably because the question was first used in a C course, then minimally adapted to Java.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking whether `m` and `n` are even instead of whether their factors are even. Besides, the inner loop is not needed, just find all the even factors of the first number and check whether all of them are also factors of the second number.

```
private static boolean isEvenSubset (int m, int n) 
{
    for(int i = 2; i < m; i++){ // note that I don't consider m itself to be a factor of m 
        if (i % 2 == 0 && m % i == 0 && n %i != 0){ // i is an even factor of m but
                                                    // not a factor of n, so return false
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true; // all the even factors of m were also factors of n
}
```

`isEvenSubset(18,12)` returns `true` and `isEvenSubset(18,32)` returns `false`.